# Script to Map the users and groups to roles of the application in websphere 8.5.5

Tags: automation, websphere, jython

Am trying to automate users and groups mapping to application in WAS below is the script that am trying i want to verify if this is how to do since i don't know much about WAS

import sys

```
filename=""
fileread = open(filename, 'r')

filelines = fileread.readlines()  

for row in filelines:
    column=row.strip().split(';')
    user_name=column[0]
    print user_name
    pass_word=column[1]
    first=column[2]
    last=column[3]


AdminTask.createUser(['-uid',user_name, '-password', pass_word, '-confirmPassword', pass_word, '-cn', first, '-sn', last ])
    AdminTask.mapUsersToAdminRole(['-roleName','Administrator','-userids',user_name])
    AdminConfig.save()
    print 'Userid creation completed for', user_name
    AdminApp.install('myapp.ear', '[-MapRolesToUsers [["All Role" No Yes "" ""]
 ["Every Role" Yes No "" ""] [DenyAllRole No No user1 group1]]]')
    agmBean = AdminControl.queryNames('type=AuthorizationGroupManager,process=dmgr,*')
AdminControl.invoke(agmBean, 'refreshAll') 

fileread.close()
```

Comment: Some things that come to mind. Have you tried running the script and see if it does what you want it to do?

Comment: Also, a denyAllRole may not be necessary if it actually denies you everything in the application because by default you shouldn't have access to anything in the application. If it actually gives access to some unrestricted resources, maybe those resources don't need to be restricted?

Comment: Also, I am not sure but I think you should have a save call after your install.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your previous question, I'm assuming you have the LDAP server set up. If you are mapping users from the LDAP server to administrator roles, then you don't need to create new users. Something like this command will map user1 from LDAP to the admin role:

```
AdminTask.mapUsersToAdminRole('[-accessids [user:defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/cn=user1,ou=users,dc=yourco,dc=com ] -userids [user1 ] -roleName administrator]')
```

The realm name can be found in wimconfig.xml under CELL_DIR/wim/config; defaultWIMFileBasedRealm is the default. I would suggest running the command manually, and when you get everything to work, write the script.